# Cross-framework Solutions for field Annotations

Tags: java, android, jpa, android-room

Does anyone have any strategies or examples of cross-framework libraries?

I am working on a project with an android app, a java server and a Java desktop client, which all use different frameworks. I need to refactor some core business logic into a separate library that can be used across all of these to ensure consistent behavior, but the field annotations are killing me.

The problem is that I am using Room in the Android app (which requires the @PrimaryKey annotation on the primary key field of a database entity) and JPA in the server and JavaFX client (which requires @Id).

Given this level of difficulty with the models, we initially copy-pasted the fields without annotations to the others when changing them. However,  the business logic needs to make use of the models and accommodate each platform's specific ORM, Http client and Json serializer. (I know that it is technically possible to get Gson, Apache Http and Hibernate to run on all of these platforms, but actually doing any of these solutions created too many nightmares of its own)

As far as I can tell, there isn't a nice solution to this. Fortunately, the same @Inject is used in Dagger2 and CDI/CDI-SE so I have created some interfaces that each platform/framework will implement.

Does anybody have any examples or case studies I could look at which might help me arrive at a solution?

(I realize this question doesn't include any code samples, but it's more of a general programming strategy question.)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDX for Java and JDXA for Android ORMs.

You may consider using JDX for Java and JDXA for Android ORM frameworks to share the common object model, the core business logic code, and the data integration code across Java server, Java desktop, and Android platforms.

JDX and JDXA don't use annotations to define the mapping - instead they use an external text file to define the mapping specification based on a simple ORM grammar. So you may use the same mapping specification for your common object model across different platforms. Also, the APIs for both JDX and JDXA are simliar.

So, you just need to use the appropriate JDX(A) ORM library for your target platform and an appropriate JDBC driver for your target database without needing to change your object model or business logic.

Comment: That looks like it might help with the database problem, but not the problems of the custom annotations for different serialization and deserialization libraries or the difference in the way dependency injection has to be handled (I thought I could get away with @Inject, but I ended up with things that would either work on Android or on Java EE).

I think the larger issue would be converting the database code we have for our server to using JDX.

Comment: Well, you may still use annotations, if needed for non-persistence reasons. JDX does not need any annotations and will essentially ignore them. Of course, you would need to use JDX APIs for data access. But that code would be portable between the Java (server) and Android platforms.

Comment: That still leaves the problem of using a different ORM and having to convert everything (we really like Room on Android and began the switch since it's alpha release) and the problem that each platform needs annotations that are found in libraries exclusive to each platform for everything else.

Comment: Please help me understand your situation better. Even if you decide to use Room on Android, won't you need a different ORM on the server side anyway? If you use a different ORM there, won't you need to use that ORM's APIs for data access? Assuming the answer is yes to both of these questions, you cannot have portable data access code. Right? Is that acceptable to you?

Comment: Having portable data access code isn't the problem since that has already been built and heavily tested on both platforms. The problem is retaining the models between the client and server in order to use them in the business logic code that will be shared. If the shared business logic code needs to use the DAOs, then we will create the minimum interfaces needed and the DAOs on each platform respectively will implement them.

Comment: OK. Seems like the current 'heavily tested' data access code on Android uses Room. What are you currently using on the server platform for this 'heavily tested' data access code?

Comment: Server is using a custom solution built on JPA for our particular purposes. The Android code is much less mature, but your product doesn't address the core problem for us.

Comment: OK. So you would like to continue to use the JPA-compatible model and code on the server side (because it is a custom solution and is already heavily tested). And you would like to use the same JPA model classes on the Android side for portability reasons but the JPA and other server-side related annotations are conflicting with annotations required by Room. Since JDXA ORM does not require its own annotations and ignores other annotations, you may be able to use it on the Android side with the same model classes. That way, you can retain the model classes between the client and the server.

Comment: By the way, both JDX and JDXA can persist JSON objects without requiring any annotations or external library for data conversion. So that means one less dependency to worry about if you are dealing with JSON objects.